# Function with SUCC

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, lisp, successor-arithmetics

I have some problems with this exercise

```
COTO(0,y)=y
COTO(x+1,y)=SUCC(SUCC(COTO(x, SUCC(y)))

COTO (1,3); COTO (2,2); COTO (3,44) - ?
```

I know that SUCC(2) = 3, for example, but I still don't have any ideas with this question. Can anybody help ? It's may be LISP language, but no answers from Google .

Comment: Substitute COTO(1,3) by the pattern that maches: here the second pattern, with X=0 and Y=3 (note: shouldn't the pattern be COTO(SUCC(X),Y) instead?). You obtain a recursive call to COTO to which you should add 2 (because you have two applications of SUCC). The recursive call is COTO(0,4), which matches the first pattern with Y=4. The result of the recursive call is thus 4. You add 2 and obtain 6.

Answer (score 2):

Going by the matching cases, writing in a human-readable notation,

```
COTO (3,44) =(2)= 2 + COTO (2,45) 
            =(2)= 2 + 2 + COTO (1,46) 
            =(2)= 2 + 2 + 2 + COTO (0,47)
            =(1)= 2 + 2 + 2 + 47
            =     2*3 + (44+3)
```

and thus in general, `COTO (n,x) = _ * n + (x + _) = _ * n + _` (do fill in the blanks).